# How can I write more columns than defined in header?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, datatables

I am using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) jQuery plugin and I have the following columns in html:

```
<tbody>
    <td class="test1">elem1</td>
    <td class="test2" style="display: none;">elem2</td>
</tbody>
```

I activate one or the other column from jQuery ( always one ).
Problem is that 'datatables' plugin yells error because num of columns from tbody is not equal with num of columns from thead (1 in my case 'cause I only want one to display).

Is there a workaround for defining more columns than specified in the header and pass validation ?

1. I am writing the html thought Django's template language.
2. For showing columns I use something like this:

> ```
>  <select onchange="selectChange(this.value)">
>     <option>test1</option>
>     <option>test2</option>
>  </select>
>
>
> function selectChange(val) {
>   $(`[class*="test"]`).hide();
>   $(`[class="${val}"]`).show();
> }
> ```

Comment: I'd define all possible column headers but then hide all but the one I need displayed.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking of that, seems extreme :) I would have tens of columns in my real case.

Comment: Shouldn't be a huge issue.  I've done tables with 20+ columns and 6k rows.  Sort/search performance didn't seem impacted.  And it might (i'm not positive) ignore hidden columns.

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) How is the source data provided to DataTables? (2) How are you performing the activation? Can you [edit] your question to show these? That may help us to suggest other options (otherwise I agree with Phaelaxz).

Comment: Wrote the answers in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. My only suggestions based on those are to take a look at [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html) and [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columnsToggle), as two ways to manage visibility, via DataTables, rather than the DOM. That still involves sending all columns to the browser.

Comment: A more radical approach would be to use ajax calls to send the one required column ID to the server, and pass back the corresponding minimal data, with the dynamic `columns: [...]` clause for table initialization. But that is probably overkill here.

Comment: what happens if you do something like `<thead><th colspan="{total number of columns}">Data</th></thead>` - where obviously you replace that with the actual number of columns

Comment: @dave, setting what you mention gives me the same error because, I think, it's expecting to have the header defined with all the columns even if you specifiy the colspan like shown [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html#:~:text=DataTables%20fully%20supports%20colspan%20and,the%20listeners%20to%20be%20added.).

Comment: But it won't help much because my number of hidden columns is changing from row to row depending upon how many options I have in the select (but I always display the same number of columns ofcourse).